# Parsing universal/fat binary files

Tags: c, mach-o, fat, universal-binary, fat-binaries

I'm working on a project to implement a basic `nm` using memory-mapping `mmap`. I have been able to parse 64-bit binaries using the code:

```
void        handle_64(char *ptr)
{
    int                     ncmds;
    struct mach_header_64   *header;
    struct load_command     *lc;
    struct symtab_command   *sym;
    int                     i;

    i = 0;
    header = (struct mach_header_64 *)ptr;
    ncmds = header->ncmds;
    lc = (void *)ptr + sizeof(*header);
    while (i < ncmds)
    {
        if (lc->cmd == LC_SYMTAB)
        {
            sym = (struct symtab_command *)lc;
            build_list (sym->nsyms, sym->symoff, sym->stroff, ptr);
            break;
         }
         lc = (void *) lc + lc->cmdsize;
         i++;
    }
}
```

According to this [link](https://lowlevelbits.org/parsing-mach-o-files/) the only difference between a mach-o and a fat binary is the `fat_header` struct above it, but simply skipping over with

```
lc = (void *)ptr + sizeof(struct fat_header) + sizeof(struct mach_header_64);
```

doesn't get me to the load_command area (segfault). How do I access the load commands of a fat/universal binary.

I'm working on a 64-bit Mac running macOS High Sierra. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got multiple problems:

- What that blog you link to calls "fat header" is more than just `struct fat_header`.
- Nowhere is it guaranteed that a Mach-O header will follow *immediately* after the fat header, just *somewhere* after it (usually Mach-O segments want to be aligned to whole pages, so putting them immediately after the fat header might not even work).
- Nowhere is it guaranteed that the 64-bit slice will be the first in the binary, nor that there even will be one.

Considering all of that, you *need* to parse the fat header (and not just ignore it) if you want any hope of getting useful results.

Now, `fat_header` is defined as follows:

```
struct fat_header {
    uint32_t    magic;      /* FAT_MAGIC or FAT_MAGIC_64 */
    uint32_t    nfat_arch;  /* number of structs that follow */
};
```

Firstly, the magic value that I usually see for fat binaries is `FAT_CIGAM` rather than `FAT_MAGIC`, despite the comment stating otherwise (take care though - this means that integers in the fat header are big endian rather than little endian!). But secondly, it is indicated that certain structs follow this header, namely:

```
struct fat_arch {
    cpu_type_t  cputype;    /* cpu specifier (int) */
    cpu_subtype_t   cpusubtype; /* machine specifier (int) */
    uint32_t    offset;     /* file offset to this object file */
    uint32_t    size;       /* size of this object file */
    uint32_t    align;      /* alignment as a power of 2 */
};
```

This works the same way a "thin" Mach-O header does with its load commands. `fat_arch.offset` is the offset from the very beginning of the file. Following that, it's quite simple to print all slices of a fat Mach-O:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mach-o/fat.h>

#define SWAP32(x) ((((x) & 0xff000000) >> 24) | (((x) & 0xff0000) >> 8) | (((x) & 0xff00) << 8) | (((x) & 0xff) << 24))

void print_fat_header(void *buf)
{
    struct fat_header *hdr = buf;
    if(hdr->magic != FAT_CIGAM)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "bad magic: %08x\n", hdr->magic);
        return;
    }
    struct fat_arch *archs = (struct fat_arch*)(hdr + 1);
    uint32_t num = SWAP32(hdr->nfat_arch);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        const char *name = "unknown";
        switch(SWAP32(archs[i].cputype))
        {
            case CPU_TYPE_I386:     name = "i386";      break;
            case CPU_TYPE_X86_64:   name = "x86_64";    break;
            case CPU_TYPE_ARM:      name = "arm";       break;
            case CPU_TYPE_ARM64:    name = "arm64";     break;
        }
        uint32_t off = SWAP32(archs[i].offset);
        uint32_t magic = *(uint32_t*)((uintptr_t)buf + off);
        printf("%08x-%08x: %-8s (magic %8x)\n", off, off + SWAP32(archs[i].size), name, magic);
    }
}
```

Note that the above function is incomplete, as it does not know the length of `buf` and thus cannot and does not check any accessed memory against it. In a serious implementation, you should make sure to never read outside the buffer you're given. The fact that your code segfaulted also hints at it not doing enough data sanitisation.